# Loader in MS Office Add-in

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

I'm creating a MS Word Add-in, which executes a long running process and I want to create some kind of loader, a gif or something like that which will show user that program is working. I see it like this: user click a button, process starts, a circle shows up on the screen and starts spinning, when process is finished, loader(this circle) disappears and messagebox informs that process is done. 
I got all the elements except this loader, can someone give any tips how to make something like this?
I'm preparing this add-in for office 2013, especially for MS Word, but I would like to make the same for Excel and PowerPoint. Technology: C# + VSTO

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard [progess bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) control or try any third-party components.

Comment: Ok, that's some idea, but now I'm thinking about something else - making a *.gif (spinning circle) which will show up during process. Can it work? Because that would be much easier.